# About sign positive or negative of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

my question is about how the inner product (usual in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) changes when applying some transformation to the vectors of said inner product. I explain

Suppose we have $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we will assume that, for example

$$\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle > 0$$

And we will also assume that there is some transformation $h:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ (not necessarily linear, but the information is useful if it is necessary to add additional properties).

**So my question is, what would the sign (positive or negative) of this product look like?**

**$$\langle h(v_{1}), h(v_{2})\rangle$$**

**I would particularly like to know what would be the properties that the transformation $h$ needs to maintain the sign or when it changes**

A particular case that I am analyzing is what happens when I multiply the vectors by any matrix, this would also help me if someone can help me

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the clarifications in the comments, I can now more confidently ask the following:

We will suppose that $h$ corresponds to a transformation such as a change of coordinates for example, and we will say that $A$ is its Jacobian matrix, so under the same previous assumptions I want to know if

$$\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle > 0$$

so what about the sign of $\langle Av_{1}, Av_{2}\rangle$

Comment: Multiplying $v_1$ and $v_2$ by a matrix, say $A$, is the same as applying a linear map $h$ whose associated matrix (relative to a fixed basis $\beta$) is $A$, that is $[h]_{\beta}^{\beta} = A$. So you are in fact investigating the sign of $\langle h(v_1), h(v_2)\rangle$ when $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map. This is consistent with your use of the word 'transformation' for $h$ (transformation tends to mean a linear map).

Comment: Unfortunately this question does not have a definitive answer. For example, say $n=2$, $v_1=(1,0)$, $v_2=(3,0)$, and we use the regular scalar product. Then $<v_1,v_2>=3$. Now let's choose $h(v)=v-(2,0)$. You can immediately see that $<h(v_1),h(v_2)><0$. But this depends on the values of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: I'm not sure about necessary conditions on $h$ for $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$ and $\langle h(v_1),h(v_2)\rangle$ to share the same sign, but there are a few sufficient conditions. One is that $h$ is an isometry. We say that $h$ is an isometry if $\|v\|=\|h(v)\|$ for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $h$ is an isometry if and only if $\langle h(v_1),h(v_2)\rangle =\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ for all $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Operators_on_inner_product_spaces).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! it helps me a lot.
Imagine that I would find that it is a bit ambiguous to think that independent of the transformation there is a general condition to keep or change the sign.
In fact, if it is possible that you can help me, my current problem (which is when h is a topological equivalence in dynamic systems) is when I have the Jacobian matrix of $h$, seeing it as a change of coordinates. Any idea to show that the sign changes or stays in that case would help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the reverse problem, what are the requirements on $A$ if you have $$\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle > 0 \implies\langle Av_{1}, Av_{2}\rangle>0$$
i.e. your linear transform is sign preserving. In short, sign preserving $\Leftrightarrow$ angle preserving $\Leftrightarrow$ $A^TA=\lambda I,\lambda>0$, $A$ is scaled rotation.

### Basis Setup

As you said, we assume $A$ is invertible (basis change), then $A^TA$ is a positive definite matrix, which have a full set of orthogonal eigenvectors. Let's use these eigenvectors as our basis.
$$
\begin{align}
A^TA&=U\Lambda U^T\\
U&=[u_1,...u_n],UU^T=I\\
\Lambda&=diag(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n),\lambda_i>0
\end{align}
$$
Then decompose $v_1,v_2$ on this basis, the condition becomes
$$
v_1=\sum_ia_i u_i,\;\;v_2=\sum_ib_i u_i,\\
\sum_ia_ib_i>0\implies\sum_i \lambda_ia_ib_i>0
$$
Next I'll show by contradiction that if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=...=\lambda_n$ is not true, then there exist $v_1,v_2$ such that the sign preserving condition is violated.

#### Proof

Assume existing two eigenvalues with different values, let them be $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$. Without loss of generality, let $\lambda_1>\lambda_2$. Then we can construct such example in their eigenspace $Span(v_1,v_2)$.

Set
$$
a_1b_1=-\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}<-\lambda_2\\
a_2b_2=\lambda_1\\
$$
Then
$$
\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle=a_1b_1+ a_2b_2=\frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}>0
$$
but
$$
\langle Av_{1},Av_{2}\rangle=\lambda_1a_1b_1+ \lambda_2a_2b_2=-\lambda_1\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}+\lambda_1\lambda_2\\
=\lambda_1\frac{-\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}<0
$$
which contradicts the sign preserving condition.

### Implication

Thus if $A$ preserves sign of any pair of $v_1,v_2\in \mathbb R^n$ then $A^TA=\lambda I,\lambda>0 $, i.e. $A$ has to be a scaled version of an orthogonal matrix / rotation matrix. Obviously, this is also sufficient for sign preserving and angle preserving.

So we proved one equivalent condition for the inner product sign preserving linear transform: $A$ has to be a scaled version of rotation. Otherwise, we cannot predict the sign of $\langle Av_{1}, Av_{2}\rangle$ from $\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle$.

---

This is related to another question, which says the orthogonality preserving linear mapping has to be a scaled rotation.

[ALL Orthogonality preserving linear maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769021/all-orthogonality-preserving-linear-maps-from-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rn/4450806#4450806)

[Prove that there is a positive real number $\lambda$, so that $A =\lambda B$, for two positive definite square matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449236/prove-that-there-is-a-positive-real-number-lambda-so-that-a-lambda-b-fo/4449450#4449450)